# в contenteditable="true" при вводе спец символа показывать список из которого можно выбрать

Tags: contenteditable

В общем я не знаю как правильно сформулировать мысль, но суть проблемы такая:

Я работаю через поле

```
<div contenteditable="true" >
```

Нужно, что бы когда пользователь писал текст и при вводе символа & или @ выводились подсказки, в моем сулчии из базы данных список слов из которых пользователь может выбрать сколько ему нужно..

самый простой пример это как в  instagram когда пользователь вводит @ то выходит поле с пользователями.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать... я весь инет перекопал и не могу понять что это вообще такое....

Пожалуйста помогите!!!

Comment: Что-то не работает код =((((

Answer (score 3):

Копать в сторону подписки на keypress - логично же?

```js
document.getElementById("ce").addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.key === "@") {
    console.log("It's time to menu!");
  }
});
```

```css
#ce {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#ce:after {
  content: " ";
}
```

```html
<p id=ce contenteditable>
```

Ну и [допилить кроссбраузерность](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) по необходимости.

Comment: Что-то не работает код =((((

Comment: @Александр, что именно и где?